# void is an invalid type for the variable onListItemClick?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I've been trying to set up a simple `onClickListener` on an android activity which extends `ListActivity`.

Within this classes on create method, I create a spinner object which when a user selects an item, an `arrayAdapter` list item is created, depending on what the user selected (populated from a cursor request). This is generated within another method within the same class.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> playerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.match_update_rows, R.id.player_name, playerItems);

    setListAdapter(playerAdapter);
```

I'm trying to add a click listener on this new list. I have added:

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PlayerFixtureScore.class);
        i.putExtra("RowId", id);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

However, I'm getting an error on the `protected void onListItemClick` line.

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
- Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
- Duplicate local variable position
- Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
- Duplicate local variable id
- Duplicate local variable l
- Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
- Duplicate local variable v
- Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
- void is an invalid type for the variable 
 onListItemClick
```

Also, if I select the `onListItemClick` line, Eclipse says `'void is an invalid type for the variable onListItemClick'`?

All works if I remove the click listener code, just cannot work out how to add the listener on the `arrayAdapter` item so I can tell which item the user has clicked on -- any help appreciated!

As requested by MyD - here is the complete class listing:
    Thanks for your prompt responses. In reply to MByD here is the complete code listing for this class. Any suggestions appreciated!

```
public class MatchUpdate extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private int cursorCounter = 0;
private int spinnerSelected;
/** Set up the db for inital use */
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
Match match;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.match_update);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    // create a spinner for fixture selection
    Spinner fixtureSpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fixtures);

    // Get all fixtures for Spinner...
    Cursor cur = myDbHelper.getFixtures();

    // create match object for cursor results
    match = new Match(cur.getCount());

    // Populate match object with Cursor results
    for (cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()) {
        match.setFixtureId(cursorCounter, cur.getInt(0));
        match.setHomeId(cursorCounter, cur.getInt(1));
        match.setHomeTeam(cursorCounter, cur.getString(2));
        match.setAwayId(cursorCounter, cur.getInt(3));
        match.setAwayTeam(cursorCounter, cur.getString(4));
        match.setDate(cursorCounter, cur.getString(5));
        cursorCounter++;
    }

    // Set up adapters for fixture spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, match.getFixtureList());

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Set up fixture spinner
    fixtureSpin.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set fixture spinner listener
    fixtureSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        spinnerSelected = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
        updatePlayers(match);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}

public void updatePlayers(Match thisMatch) {

    // Get players for selected fixture based on Spinner selection
    Cursor playerCur = myDbHelper.getFixturePlayers(
            thisMatch.getHomeId(spinnerSelected),
            thisMatch.getAwayId(spinnerSelected));

    // set up simple ArrayAdapter to hold player names
    String[] playerItems;
    playerItems = new String[playerCur.getCount()];
    int cnt = 0;

    // pull player data from cursor, into a simple array
    for (playerCur.moveToFirst(); !playerCur.isAfterLast(); playerCur
            .moveToNext()) {
        playerItems[cnt] = playerCur.getString(0);
        cnt++;

    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> playerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.match_update_rows, R.id.player_name, playerItems);

    setListAdapter(playerAdapter);

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PlayerFixtureScore.class);
        i.putExtra("RowId", id);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: please provide the (exact) code before this method

Comment: I agree with MByD -- this seems to be a problem with unbalanced delimiters (braces or parentheses) somewhere above this code.

Answer (score 5):

Method declarations need to be made in the context of a class definition.  When trying to declare a method inside another method, errors similar to this are reported.

Comment: Thanks to your comments I have moved the click listener out of the existing method and it now works correctly - thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error from trying to put an `OnClick` handler within a `MenuItem` method, so check you are outside of a `MenuItem`.